# Drools 6 many agenda-groups declarations

Tags: drools

Can i only have one agenda-group declaration for the same rule in Drools 6?

Can I put this?

```
rule "rule_x"
agenda-group "group_x"
agenda-group "group_y"
when

then
end
```

I want to active a this rule when several groups are focused.

Comment: Did you try to compile this? If not, why not? If yes, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Most rule attributes are just syntactic sugar, and agenda-group is one of them. It's easy to achieve the same effect by falling back to logic patterns.

Define

```
class Group { private String name; ... }
```

and use one instance of it as a fact to represent the currently active group. Rules will have to show an additional pattern:

```
rule in-group-one
when
    Group( name == "one" )
    ...
```

If the rule to be in several groups at the same time:

```
rule in-groups-one-two
when
    Group( name in ("one", "two") )
```

You can also mimic the behaviour of agenda group stacking.

**Later**
The idea of focussing more than one group at the same time should be considered very carefully. While it is clear that a rule in groups a, b and c should fire when these three groups are in focus, it isn't clear at all what should happen with a rule in groups a and b, or with another rule in groups a, c and d. Whatever should happe can indeed be expressed in logic, but does it make sense, and (more importantly) is it useful?